# How to install RSX-11S?

Tags: pdp-11

I'm trying to install an RSX-11S system on my LSI-11 (PDP-11/03) simulator. I was under the impression that an RSX-11S system could be generated (via 11SGEN.CMD) from an RSX-11M or RSX-11M PLUS system. The RSX-11M/RSX-11M PLUS distribution kits I managed to install (on a PDP-11/70 simulator) however don't contain that command file. (The UFD [2,20] doesn't exist or is empty.)

The documentation also mentions an 11SKIT distribution but I'm unable to locate such a kit.

Any suggestions on how to install RSX11-S?

Comment: Last time I had to do this (in about 1980) I built 11S from 11M V3.2. The standard sysgen asks "Generating RSX-11S".  [SYSGEN manual at bitsavers](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/dec/pdp11/rsx11m_s/RSX11M_V3.2_Jun79/2_Operation/AA-H625A-TC_RSX-11M_V3.2_System_Generation_Jun79.pdf).  I never looked in to building 11S from 11M+; there might well be a separate command file there since the two are quite different (whereas 11S is really just a subset 11M).

Comment: Ah, yes. 11SGEN seems to have been an invention of [11M V4.x](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/dec/pdp11/rsx11m_s/RSX11S_V4.2_Jul85/AA-2874F-TC_RSX-11S_4.2_Sysgen_Jul85.pdf).  Past my time, I'm afraid.

Comment: For me too, the last time I performed a SYSGEN for an 11S system was more than 40 years ago. I probably used a v3.2 system for that procedure as I don't recall needing an additional kit. I downloaded and installed a 11M 3.2 system and I'm now in the process of generating a 3.2 11S system. Thanks!